# OpenCart Theme Editing

Tags: php, opencart

I have downloaded and installed OpenCart v1.5.2.1. Now I'm using the default template in there.

I want to add some extra elements like `side menu bar` to that template.

How can I achieve this? How can I add new elements to my current template according to my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check [this link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=77_43_44)

or

you could buy the book titled **Opencart 1.4 Template Design** (but this for version 1.4 only)

Answer (score 0):

For side menu bar go to Extensions > Module > Category(edit) then add module and choose which ever page you like to show and where at top, right, left and bottom and save the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Logon to Admin Panel and select:-
Extensions ->  Extensions ->
select 'Themes' from the extension type drop down menu
click on the Edit button of your Default Store Theme and from the General Tab select the desired Theme from the Theme Directory drop down menu and save it.  Clear the Modifications from Extension ->  Modifications.  That's all.

Comment: 10 years later... I wonder if this answer is still relevant :)